# How do I get the opacity to stop fading with a button press?

Tags: javascript, function, button, opacity

Currently I have the opacity of lines decreasing by 3% every 400ms. I want this feature to continue, but I also want to create a button press function where once the user presses the button, the fading stops and the opacity at which the fading stops can get recorded. Thank you so much!

```
const step = 0.03

// Helper function to extract the stimulus elements
const getLines = () => 
  ['one', 'two', 'five', 'fourteen', 'fifteen']
    .map(id => document.getElementById(id))

getLines().forEach(line => line.style.opacity = 1);

// Setup event handler
var timer = undefined;
function decreaseOpacity() {
  getLines().forEach(line => {
        line.style.opacity -= step
        console.log(line.style.opacity);
  });
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    decreaseOpacity();
  }, 400);
}
decreaseOpacity();
```

Comment: [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) can help to stop the procedure if you pass `timer` as the argument. So, you can use it inside a click event listener function, for example.

Comment: For Info: You should use setInterval instead of setTimeout and redesign your code for it, because otherwise you allways go recursive (memoryleak).You should prevent negativ opacity with if-statement because it changes anything and needs only ressources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clearTimeout(timer)` to stop the timer. I used an extra variable to store the opacity for ease of access. It could work like this. I tried to guess what your lines could look like, but it's probably wrong (lol)...

```js
const step = 0.03

// Helper function to extract the stimulus elements
const getLines = () => 
  ['one', 'two', 'five', 'fourteen', 'fifteen']
    .map(id => document.getElementById(id))

getLines().forEach(line => line.style.opacity = 1);

// Setup event handler
var timer = undefined;
var opac = 1;
function decreaseOpacity() {
  opac -= step;
  if (opac>0) {
    getLines().forEach(line => {
      line.style.opacity -= step
      //console.log(line.style.opacity);
    });
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      decreaseOpacity();
    }, 400);
  }
}
decreaseOpacity();

document.getElementById("stopButton").onclick=e=>{
clearTimeout(timer);
e.target.value=opac;
}
```

```css
.line {margin:30px;line-height:0;font-size:0;border-bottom:1px solid black;}
#two {border-bottom-width:2px;}
#five {border-bottom-width:5px;}
#fourteen {border-bottom-width:14px;}
#fifteen {border-bottom-width:15px;}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="stopButton" value="Stop">
<div id="one" class="line"></div>
<div id="two" class="line"></div>
<div id="five" class="line"></div>
<div id="fourteen" class="line"></div>
<div id="fifteen" class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way for the opacity to be recorded without the user being able to see i.e 0.8, but we are able to save that data separately? Here is what I have currently: https://jsfiddle.net/codebeginner1/2kd84s1n/2/

Comment: I see. Nice experiment! Sure, you don't have to show the value to the user. You could instead send it to a database via ajax. Or maybe record a series of values in localStorage and download it as a file later. Possibilities are endless I guess.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

You can create a Constructor function to tether button methods and a timer together:

```
function FadeMechanic(element) {
  let proto = {};
  proto.start = function() {
    proto.timer = setInterval(function() {
      element.style.opacity = getComputedStyle(element).opacity - .1;
    }, 1000);
  }
  proto.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(proto.timer);
    console.log(element.style.opacity);
  }
  return proto;
}
```

---

### Example:

```js
let el = document.querySelector.bind(document),
  start = el("#start"),
  stop = el("#stop"),
  target = el("#fader");

function FadeMechanic(element) {
  let proto = {};
  proto.start = function() {
    proto.timer = setInterval(function() {
      element.style.opacity = getComputedStyle(element).opacity - .1;
    }, 1000);
  }
  proto.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(proto.timer);
    console.log(element.style.opacity);
  }
  return proto;
}

let fader = FadeMechanic(target);
start.addEventListener("click", fader.start);
stop.addEventListener("click", fader.stop);
```

```css
section {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<section id="fader"></section>
```

---

### Extending For Multiple:

Since our Constructor can be used with One Element, we simply create a Wrapper for Multiple Elements:

```
function FadeController(elements) {
  let proto = {};
  proto.elements = elements.map(FadeMechanic);
  proto.start = () => proto.elements.forEach(element => element.start());
  proto.record = [];
  proto.stop = () => proto.record.push(proto.elements.map(element => element.stop())[0]);

  proto.stopAndPrintRecord = () =>( proto.stop(), console.log(proto.record) );
  return proto;
}
```

This also allows for us to store a `record` of our current and previous stopped opacities.

---

### Example:

```js
let el = document.querySelector.bind(document),
  start = el("#start"),
  stop = el("#stop"),
  targets = [el("#fader"), el("#fader2")];

function FadeMechanic(element) {
  let proto = {};
  proto.start = function() {
    proto.timer = setInterval(function() {
      element.style.opacity = getComputedStyle(element).opacity - .1;
    }, 1000);
  }
  proto.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(proto.timer);
    return element.style.opacity;
  }
  return proto;
}

function FadeController(elements) {
  let proto = {};
  proto.elements = elements.map(FadeMechanic);
  proto.start = () => proto.elements.forEach(element => element.start());
  proto.record = [];
  proto.stop = () => proto.record.push(proto.elements.map(element => element.stop())[0]);

  proto.stopAndPrintRecord = () =>( proto.stop(), console.log(proto.record) );
  return proto;
}

let fader = FadeController(targets);
start.addEventListener("click", fader.start);
stop.addEventListener("click", fader.stopAndPrintRecord);
```

```css
section {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<section id="fader"></section>
<section id="fader2"></section>
```

---

### With your code:

```js
const step = 0.03,
click = (sel, fn) => document.querySelector(sel).addEventListener("click", fn),

// Helper function to extract the stimulus elements
  getLines = () => ['one', 'two', 'five']
  .map(id => document.getElementById(id))

function FadeMechanic(element) {
  let proto = {};
  proto.start = function() {
    proto.timer = setInterval(function() {
      element.style.opacity = getComputedStyle(element).opacity - step;
    }, 400);
  }
  proto.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(proto.timer);
    return element.style.opacity;
  }
  return proto;
}

function FadeController(elements) {
  let proto = {};
  proto.elements = elements.map(FadeMechanic);
  proto.start = () => proto.elements.forEach(element => element.start());
  proto.record = [];
  proto.stop = () => proto.record.push(proto.elements.map(element => element.stop())[0]);
  proto.stopAndPrintRecord = () =>( proto.stop(), console.log(proto.record) );
  return proto;
}

const lineFader = FadeController(getLines());

click("#start", lineFader.start);
click("#stop", lineFader.stopAndPrintRecord);
```

```html
<span id="one">one</span>
<span id="two">two</span>
<span id="three">three</span>
<span id="four">four</span>
<span id="five">five</span>

<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to clear the Timeout on a click press in order to get it to stop.

```
function stopTimeout(e) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  opacity_level = e.target.style.opacity;
}

document.getElementById("#somebutton").onclick = stopTimeout()
```